# Play store won't let me download any apps

Tags: applications, google-play-store, 4.4-kitkat

My internal storage is about 50MB and my SD Card is about 300 MB. When I want to download an app that only need 20 something MB, it says insufficient storage. Even though I delet most of my apps and make my internal storage to about 100MB, it still says insufficient storage when I want to download an app that need 20MB. Please help me to solve this problem as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

- Use high storage SD card if possible **(at least 2GB)**
- Move your installed applications into SD card from the settings.
- Reset application preferences from the **'settings > apps'**.
- Go to **'Settings > Storage'** and choose **SD card as a preferred install location**.
- **Reboot** the phone.
- Download any application after above steps.